# What would be a regex to capture DHCP host registration records?

Tags: regular-expression, dhcp

I need a regex to capture DHCP host registration records

I need to parse through a *dhcpd.conf* file, for all host reservations, and if possible capture such to a file or Bash array. So if a host reservation is defined as follows,

```
    host Service-Ethernet {
        hardware ethernet 11:11:11:11:11:11;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.3;
        option host-name "service";
    }

    host Service-Wifi {
        hardware ethernet 22:22:22:22:22:22;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.4;
    }

    host Test {
        hardware ethernet 33:33:33:33:33:33;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.5
        option host-name "test";
    }
```

Output to file or Bash array...

```
11:11:11:11:11:11, 192.168.0.3, service
22:22:22:22:22:22. 192.168.0.4,
, 192.168.0.5, test
```

If one of the three parameters is missing, leave it blank.

Even if the expression has to be applied line by line, that is still acceptable. I can wrap the expression via a Bash script that reads the configuration file line by line, of course.

Comment: Is the last line of output missing 33:33:33:33:33:33?

Comment: I wonder if there's a dedicated tool actually made for parsing the dhcpd config files. Or, more generically anything that looks like it.

Answer (score 10):

With `parse_dhcp.awk` as

```c
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

function output() {
    printf "%s, %s, %s\n", hw, fa, opt
}

$1 == "host" {
    if (NR > 1) output()
    hw = fa = opt = ""
    next
}

{sub(/;$/, "")}
$1 == "hardware"      {hw = $NF}
$1 == "fixed-address" {fa = $NF}
$1 == "option"        {opt = $NF; gsub(/"/, "", opt)}

END {output()}
```

then

```bsh
awk -f parse_dhcp.awk dhcp.conf
```

---

More obscurely, that file is valid Tcl syntax, so we just need to write the DSL so we can evaluate the file as a Tcl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc host {name data} {
    global vars
    array set vars {hardware "" fixed-address "" option ""}
    eval $data
    puts "$vars(hardware), $vars(fixed-address), $vars(option)"
}

proc unknown {cmd args} {
    global vars
    set vars($cmd) [lindex $args end]
}

set file [lindex $argv 0]
source $file
```

and

```bsh
tclsh parse_dhcp.tcl dhcp.conf
```

Comment: you can `./parse_dhcp.tcl` since you added the shebang line which tells what interpreter to use for a file when its marked executable

Answer (score 5):

The following Perl one-lines seems to almost output what you want:

```
perl -ane 'print $F[-1] =~ s/[";]//gr unless /[{}]/; print /^$/ ? "\n" : " "'
```

but I fear the input can contain sections you want to skip entirely, so more tweaking is needed:

```
perl -ane 'if (/host/ .. /}/) {
               print $F[-1] =~ s/[";]//gr unless /[{}]/;
               print /}/ ? "\n" : " "
           }'
```

which means

- if we are between lines containing `host` and `}`, we process the input, otherwise we skip it.
- if the current line doesn't contain curlies, we print the last word, having removed semicolons and doublequotes from it
- if the line contains a closing curly bracket, we print a newline, otherwise a space.

Answer (score 0):

So, I saw people answering with different and creative solutions. As a regex enthusiast, I tried to answer with regular expressions as required.

It turns out your sample is not a well formed document because of the missing semicolon in host Test statement.

You see, there's a syntax error there and it invalidates two perfectly reasonable expressions inside statement host Test: fixed-address and option.

If you want to work with well formed documents and this example was an error, then
you may use:

```
host\s+[\w\-]+\s*\{(\s+hardware\s+ethernet\s+(([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2});)?(\s*fixed-address\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3});)?(\s*option\s+host-name\s+"(.*?)";)?\s*\}
```

The substitution string will then be:

```
\2, \5, \7
```

On the other hand, if you need to address documents missing semicolons, please put a question mark after each semicolon you need to turn optional.

You may test your options in https://regex101.com/

Let me know if I made a mistake. Good luck.